# Posting Event using Facebook Graph API Javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Graph ApI of Facebook To create Event its creating event sucessfully but I want to post (as we share event Normally or as post on friends wall) event I have try it using EVENT_ID/Feed but I think I am doing somthing wrong so any one can help to solve the problem

Comment: Can you show your code?

Answer (score 0):

That's the case of a [simple post](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) with a link.

Send a `POST` request to `FRIEND_ID/feed` with the `link` parameter corresponding to your event URL.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Javascript:

```
var body = "";
var myname = "";
var myLink = "";
var myDescr = "";

FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { privacy: { "value": "EVERYONE" }, message: body, name: myname, link: myLInk, description: myDescr }, function (response) {
                            if (!response || response.error) {
                                console.log(response.error);
                            } else {
                                //DO SOME STUFF
                            }
                        });
```

Body is the Message, myname the Title of your Shared Link, myLink the link and myDescr a short description for your link